# Are there toasters with a selector for one or two slices?

Tags: energy-efficiency

I noticed that all toasters I could find (even the ridiculously expensive ones, 300 Euro/dollars) toast both slots at the same time, instead of offering a selector one/two.

The closest I could find [one expensive brand](https://www.dualit.com/products/2-slice-newgen) offering individual slices at the same time, which means either 1, 2, 3, 4 slices depending on the model.

Are there other products (which don't cost like a small TV) for two slices offering a selector for toasting only one?

Comment: I would generally focus on areas with bigger impacts. Even if you manage to halve your toaster footprint, it's not a huge part of your total.

Comment: I've used Dualit toasters a few times, in work and in group accommodation.  They're robust and repairable so make a lot of sense there (and go up to 6 slices).  They should outlast a few cheap ones in heavy use, offsetting the extra cost and saving manufacturing energy.  Otherwise I had a 4-slot in the form of 2x2 slots (I think that was Philips, but it's long gone).  I don't know about you, but I'm far more likely to eat toast at cold times of year, when the waste heat goes into warming the house anyway (which I allow to get rather cold)